# Escaped double quotes in JSON string causing error while parsing

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, gson

I am using GSON to convert the List(Map(String,String)) to json string and passing it to the front end through session. GSON is properly escaping the double qoutes with /" but the problem is coming while parsing the json string.

The JSON string generated is

```
[{"queueList": [{"Name": "Queue\"1\""}, {"Name": "Queue2"}, {"Name": "Queue3"}, {"Name": "Queue4"}]}]
```

Error I am getting in chrome while parsing is: "UnExpected Number"

Code I am using to parse is as below

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var menuItemsStr = '[{"queueList": [{"Name": "Queue\"1\""}, {"Name": "Queue2"}, {"Name": "Queue3"}, {"Name": "Queue4"}]}]';
var menuItems = $.parseJSON(menuItemsStr);
$.each(menuItems[0].queueList, function (idx, obj) {
    var listItemHTML = $("#listItem").clone().html();
    listItemHTML = listItemHTML.replace(/\@QN/g, obj.Name);

    $("#list").append(listItemHTML);
});
});
```

Below is the fiddle link where above code is present with the issue
http://jsfiddle.net/vinaybvk/qvwL9246/2/

When the JSON string has \\" then above fiddle is working fine as expected.

 Working escaped JSON string is below:

```
var menuItemsStr = '[{"queueList": [{"Name": "Queue\\"1\\""}, {"Name": "Queue2"}, {"Name": "Queue3"}, {"Name": "Queue4"}]}]';
```

I am not able to find a way to add \\ before " to get the behavior working. I am trying both in java and javascript. 

what i am trying to do in javascript is there in the above fiddle in comments

what I am trying to do in java is str.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\")); which is generating the string with \\\"

Please let me know Is there any way to get this corrected or I am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to use `JSON.parse()` at all? [this is what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/mybxatfr/)

Comment: When you write the string literally in javascript, you'll need to double escape it, one escape for the javascript parser, and one for the JSON parser.

Comment: Hi Pointy I am using parse to convert the string to JSON object so that I can parse it and iterate through that. Hi Adeneo even though I am getting the string directly from the server it is behaving the same way. I am using some thing like this to populate the variable in the JSP var jsonStr = '<%session.getAttribute("key").toString()%>';

Comment: That's like writing it literally, as the server writes it as a literal string

Comment: Pointy has a point though, why not just write it as an object, javascript supports that, no need for the quotes around it.

Comment: @adeneo, I think you're getting caught up on the difference between what comes from the server and what you type in manually. When you type it in as a javascript string you need to double escape, otherwise it treats `\"` as `"` and that's what you'll get in the string. If the server sends you something with `\"` in it that would be the equivalent of creating a string by typing in `\\"` in your code.

Comment: @redbmk - That would be true if using ajax, but when you do `var ss = '<% server output %>';`  it's exactly like typing it.

Comment: @adeneo, in that case, you'll need to do the regex on the server side. e.g. `var ss = '<% (server output).replace(/\\/, "\\") %>';` (I don't know what language you're using on the server so you'd obviously have to tweak it to work with that. If you don't have access to that you're kinda SOL because you'll have no idea where the \'s were supposed to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of quoting the string then parsing it, in this case you can just do:

```
var menuItems = <s:property value="#session['jsonFormattedResult']" escapeHtml = "false" />;
```

which results in a valid object.

Comment: I tried the above option but it is also throwing the JS error as "unexpected token {" error is same in both the fiddle I shared and the webapplication I am using

Comment: @Vinay you'll have to show code on how your server prints the string, since that's the issue.

Comment: I did a sysout in my action class with gson.toJSON(str) generated value and it gave the string as **[{"queueNamesList": [{"Name": "Inbasket"}, {"Name": "Lending Option\"s\""}, {"Name": "Work Queue"}]}]**     In the JSP page the code I am using is **var jsonFormattedResult = '<s:property value="#session['jsonFormattedResult']" escapeHtml = "false" />';** which was comming in the similar way I mentioned in the post as **var jsonFormattedResult  = '[{"queueNamesList": [{"Name": "Inbasket"}, {"Name": "Lending Option\"s\""}, {"Name": "Work Queue"}]}]';**

Comment: Based on ur input I changed the JSP code as **var jsonFormattedResult = {{<s:property value="#session['jsonFormattedResult']" escapeHtml = "false" />}};** it gave the output as **var jsonFormattedResult = {{[{"queueNamesList": [{"Name": "Inbasket"}, {"Name": "Lending Option\"s\""}, {"Name": "Work Queue"}]}]}};**

Comment: @Vinay Thanks for the update. I updated my answer with my fixed code based on it.

Comment: Thank you thats working fine, only one small problem is when there is no session variable at certain point that line is giving JS error so I am doing a if else condition to assign null when there is no session variable. Updated working code is **<s:if test="#session.jsonFormattedResult==null">
 jsonFormattedResult = null;
</s:if>
<s:else>
 jsonFormattedResult = <s:property value="#session['jsonFormattedResult']" escapeHtml = "false" />;
</s:else>**